# Unable to get property 'validate' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-validator

I have attached a validator to the container and got a reference by doing below:

```
var validator = $("#sectionContainer").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator");
```

When I run the code below I get an error saying " JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'validate' of undefined or null reference".

```
if (validator.validate()) {
    //do my logic to save form
  }
});
```

What am I doing wrong here ? Am I missing something?
Using jquery version jquery-1.10.2.js and jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js

Comment: `validator` is `null` or not defined. Ensure, validator has correct value. This is has nothing to do with jQuery directly.

Comment: Is `#sectionContainer` correct? A quick google [finds this](http://www.telerik.com/forums/myform-kendovalidator-data-kendovalidator-is-undefined) where the problem is the same - and the issue was because the initial jQuery selector was not right.

Comment: How is your HTML and JS files being loaded? Are you sure the DOM is loaded before using the selector?

Comment: @JamesThorpe I have checked and validated that #sectionContainer is correct.

Comment: @adrield very good point... how do I check how is html and js loaded. Because that makes sense if dom isin't loaded before this line then it would come undefined.

Comment: Ok so what I ended up doing is define validator inside my ready function. After doing so validation was not going null anymore. Thanks for pointing me in right direction @adrield!! :)

Comment: @HereToLearn, I'm glad to help! :)